# How to remove last whitespace of a single line output inside a loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I want my output to be in a single line that's why I was using `end = ' '` but since it is in a loop, It also adds space after the last value which I don't want. I tried using `strip()` but it removes every space. so How do I remove the last space from my output in that loop?

```
import math

f0 = int(input())
r = math.pow (2, 1/12)
for i in range(5):
    f1 = f0 * (r ** i )
    print('{:.2f}'.format(f1), end= ' ')
```

**Expected Output: If 440 is Input**
`440.00 466.16 493.88 523.25 554.37`

**My Output :**`440.00 466.16 493.88 523.25 554.37`

Comment: you can use rstrip() to strip the right most space.

Comment: @SangeerththanB You can't use `str.rstrip` after the string has been printed. To use `str.rstrip` you'd have to build up the string first, but if you're building the string from an iterable you might as well just use `str.join` for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Yes that's correct its better to go with join().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider replacing your for loop with a generator expression along with `str.join` like so:

```
print(' '.join((f'{f0*r**i:.2f}' for i in range(5))))
```

Output: `440.00 466.16 493.88 523.25 554.37`

This approach saves you from having to have different behaviour on the last iterator of the loop, or editing the string afterwards.

`str.join` inserts the string (`' '` in this case) between each element of the iterable, but not at the beginning or end.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thank you it helped!
I tried `str.join` before but I did it inside the loop so it outputs the same result but replacing the loop with the following expression solved!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a if-else statement and apply it for the last iteration of the loop.

```
import math

f0 = int(input())
r = math.pow(2, 1/12)
for i in range(5):
    f1 = f0 * (r ** i )
    if i == 5:
        print('{:.2f}'.format(f1))
    else:
        print('{:.2f}'.format(f1), end= ' ')
```